# Triangle inequality in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider $f_n$ as sequence of non negative functions and $f_n \in L^p(\mu),\: 1 \leq p < \infty$. I want to prove that the following holds:
$$\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  f_k\|_p \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \|f_k\|_p $$
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$\|\cdot \|_p$ is a norm. Therefore, for all $n$, $$\left\|\sum_{k=0}^n f_k\right\|_p\leq \sum_{k=0}^n\|f_k\|_p.\tag{*}$$
Fatou's lemma allow you to conclude.

---

**Edit**

Set $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^nf_k$ and $S_\infty =\lim_{n\to \infty }S_n$.

$$\left\|S_\infty \right\|_p=\left\|\liminf_{n\to \infty }S_n\right\|_p\underset{Fatou}{\leq} \liminf_{n\to \infty }\|S_n\|_p\underset{(*)}{\leq}\liminf_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=0}^n\|f_k\|_p\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|f_n\|_p.$$

Comment: Why can't I argue like Joel Biffin for a fixed n? Im am not sure how you would apply Fatou's lemma: If I knew that the limit of the sum of the non negative function exits, than the liminf would exist.

Comment: @Leon1998: If $\left\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k\right\|_p=\infty $, then the result is obviously true. Notice that $\left\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k\right\|_p^p=\int\underbrace{\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k\right|^p}_{\geq 0}$, so Fatou's lemma can be used.

Comment: Why are you considering $||.||_p^p$ Do want to apply Fatou's lemma on that?

Comment: Fatou's lemma states the following then: $ lim inf \int |\sum_ k f_k|^p \leq  \int  lim inf |\sum_ k f_p|^k  $

Comment: Now I only have to ensure, that the limit exists. Then it follows lim=liminf

Comment: No, Fatou's lemma states $\int\liminf_{n\to \infty }|f_n|\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty }\int|f_n|.$

Comment: When you write $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n$ then the limit is supposed to exist (and can be eventually $\infty $). @Leon1998

Comment: Sorry,  $ \int \liminf  |\sum_k f_k|^p \leq  \liminf \int   |\sum_k f_k|^p$

Comment: How do I get the sum out of $| ... |$  @Surb?

Comment: @Leon1998: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inequality in $\ L^p(\mu)\ $ is known as [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).  You can find a proof of it in the above-linked Wikipedia article (which I have not checked for correctness), or just about any decent book on [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis).  Once you have the simple triangle inequality, you can establish your inequality by the methods explained in the other answers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. Minkovsky is not enough.

Comment: But neither do any of the other answers necessarily answer the OP's question, in my opinion, since they *assume* that he already knows the proof that $\ \vert\vert . \vert\vert_p\ $ *is* a norm, which may not be the case.  I saw no point in repeating the information already given in those answers.

Comment: It is of course a norm. It's the $L^p$ norm. What else ?

Comment: And how do you prove that?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are working with the $L^p(\mu)$ norm is not important. By definition of a norm, the triangle inequality holds and specifically here it holds for nonnegative functions.

Take the definition $\lVert f_1 + f_2 \rVert_p \le \lVert f_1 \rVert_p + \lVert f_2 \rVert_p$, then take $g_2 = f_2 + f_3$ we can then use the definition again (since $f_i$ are nonnegative) to yield,

$$\lVert f_1 + g_2 \rVert_p \le \lVert f_1 \rVert_p + \lVert g_2 \rVert_p = \lVert f_1 \rVert_p + \lVert f_2 + f_3 \rVert_p \le \lVert  f_1\rVert_p + \lVert f_2\rVert_p + \lVert f_3\rVert_p,$$

$$\text{i.e.} \quad \lVert f_1 + f_2 + f_3 \rVert_p \le \lVert  f_1\rVert_p + \lVert f_2\rVert_p + \lVert f_3\rVert_p.$$

Then we can repeat for all $n$ by taking $g_n = f_n + f_{n+1}$ and hence we have proved the theorem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. The sub-linearity is not enough.